# Swagger PreAuthorize bearer token

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, swashbuckle

Pre-fill the Bearer token with a JWT returned from service and set and set Authorized to True, so the user does not have to manually click the authorize button and enter the token. But UI just doesn't send the property authorization.

> Swagger UI

```
ui = SwaggerUIBundle({
                    url: "https://localhost:44318/swagger/v1/swagger.json",
                    onComplete: function () {

                        // Default API key
                        ui.preauthorizeApiKey("bearer", token);
                    }
                })
```

> Security Scheme

```
            c.AddSecurityDefinition("bearer", new OpenApiSecurityScheme {
                Description = x.SwaggerAuthorization_desc,
                Name = "Authorization",
                In = ParameterLocation.Header,
                Type = SecuritySchemeType.ApiKey,
                Scheme = "Bearer",
            });

            c.AddSecurityRequirement(new OpenApiSecurityRequirement
            {
                {
                    new OpenApiSecurityScheme
                    {
                        Reference = new OpenApiReference {
                            Type = ReferenceType.SecurityScheme,
                            Id = "bearer"
                        }
                    },
                    new string[] {}
                }
            });
```

---

SwaggerUI: 5.0.0

OpenAPI: 3.0.1

SecuritySchemes: Bearer

---

Comment: _"UI just doesn't send the property authorization."_ - what actually happens and how is it different from the expected result?

Comment: When I open the console, I see that the token authorization has not been sent. So my status is 401.